# Problem regarding inverstion of order of summation

Tags: real-analysis

Theorem 8.3 in Baby Rudin states the following:

> Given a double sequence $\{a_{ij}\}$, $i=1,2,3, ..., j=1,2,3, ...$, suppose that
>   $$
> \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |a_{ij}| = b_i ~~~~~~~~~~ (i=1,2,3,...)
> $$
>   and $\sum b_i$ converges. Then
>   $$
> \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_{ij} = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_{ij}.
> $$

The question I have is regarding Exercise 2 from the same chapter:

> Let $a_{ij}$ be the number in the $i$th row and $j$th column of the array
>   \begin{matrix}
>   -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
>   \frac{1}{2} & -1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
>   \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2} & -1 & 0 & \cdots \\
>   \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2} & -1 & \cdots \\
>   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\vdots
>  \end{matrix}
>   so that
>   $$
> a_{ij} = \begin{cases} 0 & (i<j) \\ -1 & (i=j) \\ 2^{j-i} & (i>j) \end{cases}
> $$
>   Prove that 
>   $$
> \sum_i\sum_ja_{ij}=-2, \sum_j\sum_ia_{ij}=0.
> $$

The result is evident simply by inspection, but does it not contradict the theorem stated above? I must be missing something obvious...

Comment: Notice that $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |a_{ij}| = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{-n} = 2 = b_i$, so $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} b_i$ does not converge.

Comment: @msteve Oh wow, I actually missed that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theorem 8.3, the absolute value signs ensure that all the sums converge absolutely.  In that case, you can rearrange the order of summation at will.  The exercise has both positive and negative terms.  If you take the absolute value of all the terms, the sum is infinite. This shows the convergence is conditional and reordering the summation is not allowed without some proof that the sum is not changed.

Comment: Thank you! I completely missed the absolute value sign :(